# MySQL INSERT using PHP fail: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql

My `add.php` file is used to add submission of a form into 5 different tables namely: `parents`, `children`, `child_state`, `others` and `contributions`. The file is here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ca990a7de5458248fe3a

Inserting data into the `parents` table works fines, but inserting to `children`, `child_state` and `others` tables fails with the below error:

*Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails*

Can a PHP/MySQL genius be able to point out my mistake or error?

Comment: the `$lastinsert = mysqli_insert_id($dbcon);` seems to be the problem. It returns 0 (zero)

Comment: It would be useful if you add the DDL statements for the respective tables.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_insert_id` only returns the id of the last inserted row if the table has an AUTO_INCREMENT field (if you don't have an AUTO_INCREMENT on one of your fields in your table, then the function `mysql_insert_id` will return 0). Your table doesn't seem to have one. Either changed `f_id` to have an AUTO_INCREMENT attribute or get the ID of the last inserted row differently.